# Function returns Null :: laravel

Tags: php, function, laravel-4, null

I have a function which gets the value from a database and returns. When I echo, the value does exist. But returned value is null;

```
public static function getCountryCode($country) {       
    $country = (int) $country;      
    $x = Country::where('id', $country)->get();
    $country_code = '';         
    foreach($x as $row)             
        $country_code = $row->alpha_2;
    //return 'bd';      
    echo $country_code;         
    return $country_code; 
}
```

Not sure what's wrong in there. It's a laravel project.

Function that is calling this method

```
public function countryselect()
{
    $country_id = HomeController::detectCountry();
    $country_code = SiteController::getCountryCode($country_id);
    var_dump($country_code);
    return View::make('Layout.countryselect', compact('country_id', 'country_code'));
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that calls this method?

Comment: `public function countryselect()
 {
  $country_id = HomeController::detectCountry();
  $country_code = SiteController::getCountryCode($country_id);
  var_dump($country_code);
  return View::make('Layout.countryselect', compact('country_id', 'country_code'));
 }`

Comment: It'll be easier to format if you add it to the question. There's a pending edit there though that needs bringing in too.

Comment: this is function that is used to call @ bcmcfc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use "foreach" function. You can get country code in much easier way. Just make some changes in getCountryCode() like

```
public static function getCountryCode($countryId) {
    $countryId = (int) $countryId;      
    $country = Country::where('id', $countryId)->get()->first();
    return $country->code;
}
```

This will return the country code of specified country id. Use descriptive name for variable like you used for the function

Comment: thnx for letting me know this